Click a particular button on a page using By.LINK_TEXT but find_element throws exception
On this page: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/KO/options
Is this button:
<button class="tertiary-btn fin-size-small menuBtn tw-justify-center rounded rightAlign svelte-xhcwo" data-ylk="elm:inpt;elmt:menu;itc:1;sec:qsp-options;slk:date-select;subsec:date" type="button" aria-label="May 24, 2024" aria-haspopup="listbox" data-type="date" data-rapid_p="14" data-v9y="1">
  <div class="icon fin-icon inherit-icn sz-medium svelte-21xhfv">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M16.59 8.59 12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z"></path>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <span class=" textSelect svelte-q648fa">May 24, 2024</span>
</button>

I tried this code:
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/KO/options")
# The option expiraiton date will change based on when this script runs 
option_expiration_date = "May 24, 2024"
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, option_expiration_date)))
elem = browser.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, option_expiration_date)
elem.click()

but it throws this exception:
Message=Message: 
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:193:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:511:5
dom.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/shared/DOM.sys.mjs:136:16

  Source=C:\Users\Leave\source\repos\Selenium Demo\Selenium Demo\src\demoPackage\yahooFinance.py
  StackTrace:
  File "C:\Users\Leave\source\repos\Selenium Demo\Selenium Demo\src\demoPackage\yahooFinance.py", line 18, in yahooFinance
    field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, option_expiration_date)))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Leave\source\repos\Selenium Demo\Selenium Demo\src\mainPackage\main.py", line 17, in <module> (Current frame)
    yahooFinance()
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:193:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:511:5
dom.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/shared/DOM.sys.mjs:136:16


This is how you can click that button, using an XPATH based locator:
//[... imports, define browser, etc ... make sure browser's window is tall enough, at least 1500px]

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/KO/options?guccounter=1')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@name="agree"]'))).click()
driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/KO/options?guccounter=1')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@aria-label="May 24, 2024"]'))).click()

Selenium documentation can be found here.

By.LINK_TEXT is used to find a hyperlink by contained text. A hyperlink is an A tag so it can't be used to click that BUTTON tag. But, with a minor change we can get your script working. The code below has been tested and is working.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/KO/options")
# The option expiration date will change based on when this script runs
option_expiration_date = "May 24, 2024"
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//button[@aria-label='{option_expiration_date}']"))).click()

